# Can't Connect Zend to MySQL

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm new to the Zend Framework and trying to figure some stuff out.  I wonder if anyone could help me figure out why I'm unable to connect to a MYSQL database on my live server (a Cpanel / shared style webhost).

I've taken the following steps.

1. Built the Zend framework
2. Uploaded to a folder on the webhost
3. Added the "ZEND" folder to the libraries
4. Added the connect string stuff to the application.ini file *(a)
5. Reloaded the page

*(a)
    The connection information I've added goes like this:

```
 resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
 resources.db.params.host = localhost
 resources.db.params.username = cpanel_dbuser
 resources.db.params.password = 123456
 resources.db.params.dbname = cpanel_db
```

the error I'm getting reads like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Error parsing /home/path/application/configs/application.ini on line 13 ' 
in /home/path/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php:181 Stack trace: 
    #0 /home/path/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(201): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/home/path/...') 
    #1 /home/path/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(125): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/home/path/...') 
    #2 /home/path/library/Zend/Application.php(383): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/home/path/...', 'production') 
    #3 /home/path/library/Zend/Application.php(85): Zend_Application->_loadConfig('/home/path/...') 
    #4 /home/path/public/index.php(25): Zend_Application->__construct('production', '/home/path/...') 
    #5 {main} thrown in /home/path/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 18
```

**EDIT**
Line 13 of my application.ini is the password.
Which has an exclamation point in it.
Which if I change the password for the database user now works.

No exclamation points in Zend DB passwords.

Comment: You can accept your own answer or at least add "[SOLVED] in front of the question.

Comment: I will add SOLVED now, thanks for the reminder.  Unfortuantely there's a 2 day time delay before I can accept my own answer.  *Very* sorry for the time waster.

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar  I don't think adding [solved] is a common practice on SO.

Comment: No it's not. But I was not sure if you can accept your own answer :) Without it people who don't read other answers might add their own answers or ask some more questions about setup and stuff. It's inefficient :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI - please don't struggle to answer this for me.

Up above I've already answered the question:

**No exclamation points in Zend DB passwords.**

I'd delete the question but for the sake of others' I thought I'd leave the answer here. (Search engines might save someone a bit of time)

Comment: @Tim: He has to wait before SO lets him do that.

Comment: Yep, there's a two day delay before I can accept an answer.  I've edited "SOLVED" into the title so I don't ruin anyone else's day (I'd have deleted the post if I didn't think a search engine might find it for someone some day) - anyways - first person to answer the question in any way shape or form gets the free "answer" points. Just say "you answered the question above - no exclamation marks" and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Does your solution preclude quotation marks around your password? Your example .ini doesn't quote any of your values.

Comment: I didn't try quotation marks.  you think that makes a difference? All the versions of INI files I'd seen don't have quotes anywhere.  Doesn't mean you can't do it ... but I guess I just assumed.